# Publish deployment package into Windows Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, orchardcms, azure-web-roles, web-platform-installer

I plan to use two websites in a single web role. Ref: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx).
I can do it easily when Web Poject source code. However I need to install Orchard & Magelia (shopping cart) together. They are available as deployment package.

Q.1. Can I wrap deployment package into azure solution?

Q.2. If not, should I download source code of orchard & Magelia then publish? I wonder how other community members are working on this !

Related question [here](https://mageliawebstore.codeplex.com/discussions/476972#post1141077) on codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

Copy binary published package via FTP to azure website.